# fluentd indices not adding to elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, efk, iks

I've deployed EFK stack in IBM Kuberentes cloud by following the step by step guide from [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-logging-stack-on-kubernetes#step-4-creating-the-fluentd-daemonset). Every deployment is done successfully, all EFK stack are deployed fine, but I'm unable to find `fluentd` indices in elastic search, [image: elasticsearch not showing fluentd indices]

I'm unable to create index pattern in kibana for log-data[image: kibana not showing fluentd]